# Как сконвертировать ключи OpenSSH в .pfx или .p12?

Tags: ssh, openssl

Есть ключи, сгенерированные *OpenSSH*: `id_dsa`, `id_rsa`.
Хочу записать их на USB-токен. Для этого нужно сгенерировать сертификаты в формате `.p12` или `.pfx`, содержащие эти ключи.

Как это можно сделать?

Под руками есть Ubuntu 14.04 и Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Формат PKCS#12 — это формат, предназначенный для хранения ключевой пары (закрытый ключ и сертификат)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS12)

одного лишь закрытого ключа недостаточно: нужен ещё и сертификат (стандарта [x.509](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509)).

---

```
$ openssl rsa -in id_rsa -out rsa.private.key
$ openssl req -new -key rsa.private.key -out rsa.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in rsa.csr -signkey id_rsa -out rsa.crt
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in rsa.crt -inkey rsa.priv -out rsa.p12
```

Сохранённый в нём ключ можно извлечь и проверить:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in rsa.p12 -out private.key -nodes
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
```

ключ идёт в формате *private key*, конвертируем его в *rsa private key*:

```
$ openssl rsa -in private.key -out rsa.private.key.2
writing RSA key
```

и сверяем с исходным:

```
$ md5sum rsa.private.key*
af2d5e3c086ab61d68c8f4b1b09a05c3  rsa.private.key
af2d5e3c086ab61d68c8f4b1b09a05c3  rsa.private.key.2
```

---

p.s. с *dsa* всё точно так же, только все упоминания слова *rsa* надо заменить на *dsa*.

Comment: Сертификат на токене всё равно нужен хоть какой (самоподписанный, истекший - без разницы). Вот именно этой простой команды мне и нехватало чтобы таки запихнуть мой ключ внутрь сертификата. Спасибо. Добавь к себе в ответ еще генерирование сертификата: openssl req -new -key id_rsa.priv -out rsa.csr; openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in rsa.csr -signkey id_rsa -out rsa.crt и я ответ как готовый отмечу

Comment: А вообще потом еще немного поискал и нашел удобный GUI: XCA http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/ для windows есть бинарник, для ubuntu просто из репозитория ставится - всё сразу становится просто и понятно

Comment: здесь принята и приветствуется практика дополнения/исправления вопросов/ответов. репутации у вас для этого, вроде бы, достаточно.

Comment: К сожалению, при импорте «Ошибка токена: неверное значение атрибута». При этом pfx для Authenticode-то нормально импортировался и работает. Что же такого волшебного в том pfx, что он подошёл, а этот синтетический — ни в какую.